# On-Device Hardware decryption in the browser possible?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography

I'm basically trying to see if there are any devices out there that can take an encrypted string from a browser, decrypt it on the device so that the private key never leaves it, and then send the decrypted content back into the browser.

I know this can be done with gpg etc. on the command line, but for the sake of user experience, I am trying to keep this in a browser. I've looked into using a Yubikey, but it does not seem to support this functionality. Any hardware pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Generally you'd program a browser extension to do such a thing, but note that they are on the decline as well...

Comment: Hi Maarten, appreciate the response. Any pointers or examples that have successfully achieved this?

Comment: I only know of some big parties that provide solutions like this. Browser based security always has been a mine-field... Too many browsers, too much chance that an attacker has you decrypt a string by sending you to his own server etc.